# Html5 canvas issue on MacOS chrome

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to plot a scatter plot using HTML5 canvas. My scatter plot needs to have a lot of points. When I try to plot a large number of points let's say (7700000) points on a canvas it works on Firefox and Safari.

[Very large number of points (JS fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/v936t7d1/1/)

But for some reason the canvas is blank on Google Chrome on MacOS. However it works on Google Chrome of Windows and Linux. If the number of points to be plotted are smaller, it works on MacOS but doesn't when the number of points is increased. I tried to search for the related issues but could not find any. Am I doing something wrong or is it the issue with Google Chrome for MacOS?

[Small number of points (JS Fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/shz32kqL/)

I am using following function to plot on canvas:

```
function drawPoint(scaleX, scaleY, point, k) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = pointColor;
    const px = scaleX(point[0]);
    const py = scaleY(point[1]);
    const arc_width = width/1000;
    const arc_height = height/1000;
    // context.arc(px, py, arc_width * k, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.strokeRect(px, py, arc_width * k, arc_height * k)
    context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Are your real data points really floored like in your example? If so, it makes no sense to draw that many points. Your grid can only contain 900 x 900 points. Filter out every duplicates. Also, don't paint each point on its own, create a big path and paint it in a single call. Finally, avoid stroke, it's super slow, prefer fill when you can.

Comment: My real data points are not filled it can be dynamic based on some properties of the plot. Also the points can be random it may not be in a single path.

Comment: Using fill instead of stroke solved my problem. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes, if all your points are drawn using the same color you can draw them in a single path. To do so, call once `context.beginPath()` in `draw` before you loop over your points, then in `drawPoint` you only call `context.rect(...)` (or `moveTo(x+radius,y); arc(...)`, and after, bck in `draw` you call only once `context.fill()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fill instead of stroke fixed my problem. I don't know the actual reason but when you are trying to plot large number of points on canvas, using fill is faster and solves this issue on chrome MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

You have some funky d3 animation for svg/canvas (i'm not sure why you use both). It is a transition delay that kills performance. I can load small points on Android phone, but when i rotate or resize, it redraws them all and they look entirely different. Then the page crashes.

Comment: SVG is just an overlay on top of canvas to make the plot interactive and add some features. If I try to plot these large number of points using SVG it will crash the browser so I am using canvas to plot the points and svg for interaction. In case of zooming or resizing I have another code that plots only the points in that window. Right now this is a dummy code of the actual implementation to  ask you guys about the issue that I am facing.

Comment: I mean the first paint of the canvas is a wash of monochrome noise, but on rotate it's larger stroked circles. You say you synchronize both for performance sake. In terms of interaction, svg generally updates the specific element (fast) whereas canvas redraws the whole context (slow). Browsers significantly slowdown or crash during a layout shift like this. A tiered grouping system which plots details on focus/zoom would be more user-friendly.